# How to use/create unique_lock in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, locking

Please, can anybody explain how to use and create an unique_lock in c++?
It should be used both to get mutual exclusion to any procedure of the monitor and to be able to perform wait() on the condition variable...I'm not understanding from the documentation how I am supposed to create it. Is necessary a mutex? Here is a pseudo-code:

```
/* compile with g++, flags -std=c++0x -lpthread */

#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class monitorTh {

private:

    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable waitP;
    std::condition_variable waitC;
    char element[32];
    std::unique_lock::unique_lock l;

public:
    void produce(char* elemProd) {
        l.lock();
        if (/*already_present_element*/) {
            waitP.wait(l);
        }
        else {/*produce element*/}
        l.unlock();
    }

    void consume() {
        /*something specular*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    monitorTh* monitor = new monitorTh();
    char prodotto[32] = "oggetto";

    std::thread producer([&]() {
        monitor->produce(prodotto);
    });

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
        monitor->consume();
    });

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`std::unique_lock` use the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern.

When you want to lock a mutex, you create a local variable of type `std::unique_lock` passing the mutex as parameter. When the unique_lock is constructed it will lock the mutex, and it gets destructed it will unlock the mutex. More importantly: If a exceptions is thrown, the `std::unique_lock` destructer **will** be called and so the mutex will be unlocked.

Example:

```
#include<mutex>
int some_shared_var=0;

int func() {
    int a = 3;
    { //Critical section
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
        some_shared_var += a;
    } //End of critical section
}
```

Comment: Why don't you need a `new` keyword in order to create the lock?

Comment: @ProQ It's created on the stack. If you used the new keyword, it wouldn't be destructed when you leave the scope.

Answer (score 12):

A more detailed sample code using condition variables:

```
#include<mutex>
std::mutex(mu); //Global variable or place within class
std::condition_variable condition; //A signal that can be used to communicate between functions

auto MyFunction()->void
{
  std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
  //Do Stuff
  lock.unlock(); //Unlock the mutex
  condition.notify_one(); //Notify MyOtherFunction that this is done
}

auto MyOtherFunction()->void
{
   std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
   condition.wait(lock) //Wait for MyFunction to finish, a lambda can be passed also to protects against spurious wake up e.g (lock,[](){return *some condition*})
   lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: the explicit unlocking is unnecessary. look up how a unique_lock() behaves.

Comment: @Prab, just to give the explanation: unique_lock() is automatically released when the destructor is called meaning it is exception safe and that it automatically unlocks when you leave scope.

Comment: @EliSquared you're repeating what I've already mentioned in my comment to the author

Comment: @pcodex cppreference states about the explicit unlocking: "Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)".

Comment: @Leherenn by using a unique lock you are granting control over the mutex to the lock object. That is the whole point of RAII. There is no need to manually unlock.

Comment: @pcodex In the second case I agree, but the first one seems valid to me if performance are important. The condition will potentially be notified before the mutex is unlocked otherwise. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Leherenn you might consider putting "Do Stuff" inside its on scoped block together with the lock. That would be more in the RAII spirit, and you might also save a few cpu instructions for what it's worth.

Comment: What if MyOtherFunction() locks mu first before MyFunction()? Wouldn't the first caller of "std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu)" block others?

Answer (score 6):

`std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` holds a lock on a separate `std::mutex` object. You associate the lock object with the mutex by passing it in the constructor. Unless you specify otherwise, the mutex will be immediately locked. If the lock object holds the lock when it is destroyed then the destructor will release the lock. Typically, the `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` object will thus be a local variable, declared at the point where you wish to acquire the lock.

In your case, the `produce()` function could be written like this:

```
void produce(char* elemProd) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m); // lock the mutex
    while (/*already_present_element*/) { // condition variable waits may wake spuriously
        waitP.wait(lk);
    }
    {/*produce element*/}
    // lk releases the lock when it is destroyed
}
```

Note that I have replaced the `if` with a `while` to account for spurious wakes from the `wait()` call.

Comment: You have an `else` without an `if`.

Answer (score -7):

In this case, I think all you need to do is:

```
m.lock();
// Critical section code
m.unlock();
```