# Reading from std::map without atomic flag on write

Tags: c++

I have a std::map `myMap` and a std::atomic `myLock`.

The write is:

```
if(myLock == 0)
{
   myLock++;
   myMap.insert(key, value);
   myLock--;
}
```

If I do something like this without locking from another thread, is this considered undefined behavior? The key thing is, I do not mind if the results are not accurate (ie a value in the map updated after I iterated past it). I just don't want to crash.

```
MyConstIterator endIt = mMap.cend();
for(MyConstIterator it = myMap.cbegin(); it != endIt; ++it)
{ 
}
```

I'm trying to achieve lock less reads without a mutex, but I know std::map is not thread safe. Do I have to add to the atomic lock to avoid a crash?

Comment: Why are you opposed to using a mutex?

Comment: Your use of lock won't make your map thread safe.  Think about it.  Two threads can read myLock == 0 and head into your brace.  You need a mutex.

Comment: There is no lock at all in the provided code. It is undefined behavior from here to Kathmandu.

Comment: thanks, that's an answer. feel free so I can accept.

Comment: There are 2 moments to consider 1. `std::atomic` is not free and has it's price. 2. if you think that it is so easy to beat implementation that written by experts by writing this "spinlock", think again and test - you will be surprised.

Comment: Not the point of the question, but thank you. I already understand. And as specified, this is not a spin lock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of lock won't make your map thread safe. Two threads can read `myLock == 0` and head into your brace.

You need a mutex.  [This answer on locking may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709233/how-to-use-create-unique-lock-in-c).

Comment: So what if I were to change it to ++myLock == 1 check instead? It's atomic, so the threads can't possibly see 1 at the same time.

Comment: @user99999991, Do you have a specific reason for trying to write your own lock?

Comment: I do not want to wait on a mutex. If there is a lock, I just want to continue on. It's a very lightweight piece of code that doesn't have to ensure it's writing in lock step. Atomic seemed to be the best route.

Comment: Mutex has a [trylock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock) function.  There's also [Boost Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lockfree.html).

Comment: I will take a look at it. But for curiosity sake, does ++m_Lock == 1 hold the thread safety? Because m_Lock is atomic, both threads should be safe when writing. When reading, I do not think it is safe unless I add a similar ++m_Lock == 1 check correct? I made a simple console app that continuously reads in 1 thread, and 3 other threads continuous writing. It appears to work, but I do not know if Im actually in undefined behavior.

Comment: There are things like instruction reordering to consider, though I'm not an expert on this (or anything), I do remember [reading about such things in Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lock-free-code-a-false-sense-of-security/210600279) a while back when I was thinking a lock-free impl would be a good idea.

Comment: @user99999991 `std::atomic` only makes operations on atomic itself thread safe and nothing else, `std::mutex` is different, so no your spin lock will not work properly and most probably would be less efficient than standard mutex.